# How do I replace a substring that occurs after a certain number of spaces in a string?

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm extracting data from a file in this format:

`1111 1.0 2222 53.5 3333 0.3 4444 541.1 5555 0.3'

Now suppose I want to replace `0.3` with `32.2`. How do I best go about it in Java?

I thought of using `str.replaceAll(str.substring(beginIndex, endIndex), replacement)`. However, it requires a beginning and end Index, which I can't easily provide.

What's the best method in Java?

EDIT: there may be multiple instances of 0.3. I only wish to change the one that occurs after a certain no. of spaces. This one occurs after 5 spaces, for example.

Comment: Why can't you easily find the beginning and end indicies? Is there some other problem, like multiple instances of `0.3` in your string?

Comment: Your question was very unclear, for the record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following in concise and dynamically adaptable.  I instantiated variables to provide an example, but the crucial parts are the first and last lines of the code:

```
String regex = "(?<=\\s{%s})%s(?=\\s{%s})";
String numSpaces = "1";
String number = "0.3";
String replacement = "32.2";
String yourString = "1111 1.0 2222 53.5 3333 0.3 4444 541.1";
yourString = yourString.replaceAll(String.format(regex, numSpaces, number, numSpaces),
                                   replacement);
System.out.println(yourString);
//prints 1111 1.0 2222 53.5 3333 32.2 4444 541.1
```

In this example, `"(?<=\\s{%s})%s(?=\\s{%s})"` would become: `(?<=\\s{1})0.3(?=\\s{1})`
 which means `"0.3"` with one whitespace tokens before and after, it takes advantage of positive look behinds and aheads so that only the number is replaced and the spaces are left the same.

Also, note that `replaceAll()` should only be used when dealing with regular expressions.  If you're not using regular expressions, use `.replace()` instead.  `.replace()` replaces all instances, too, the name is slightly misleading.

Note, if the number of spaces before and after are supposed to be different, just change the final argument to `String.format()` to be whatever number of spaces should be after the number.

**EDIT**:
Apparently we're defining spaces differently.  I assumed that a certain number of spaces literally means a certain number of spaces before and after the number in question.

Comment: You're missing a `;` at the end of your last line of code. Also, this input: `"0.35 1111 1.0 2222 53.5 3333 0.3 4444 540.3"` gives this output: `0.35 1111 1.0 32.232.232.232.2 53.5 3333 0.3 4444 540.3`. I don't *think* this works right now. Also, the input he specifically gave gives this output: `1111 1.0 32.232.232.232.2 53.5 3333 0.3 4444 541.1`

Comment: @mikeyaworski Thanks, fixed that.  Forgot about how java's format method works, and apparently how `.replaceAll()` works, too.  This works now!

Comment: He meant, the 0.3 occurs after 5 other numbers seperated by spaces, not that it has 5 leading spaces in front of it.

Comment: @SpiderPig Oh, lol, well I guess he edited it, but that's obviously not how I interpreted "spaces."  I do not have time to change it as this point, however.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
  String str="1111 1.0 2222 53.5 3333 0.3 4444 541.1 ";

  str=str.replaceAll(" 0.3 ", " 32.2 ");    
  System.out.println(str);
```

Comment: This won't work if `0.3` is at the beginning or the end of the string. I didn't downvote though.

Comment: @mikeyaworski, The OP mentioned, it will occur at certain number of spaces. He don't tell that it will occur at beginning or end.

Comment: In your method, there is not need for `replaceAll()`, instead this would use `replace()`.

Comment: @mikeyaworski `replace()` also replaces all of the occurrences. `replaceAll()` does the same, but expects a regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to replace ALL of the `0.3`s in your String (**tested and works**):

```
String s = "1111 1.0 2222 53.5 3333 0.3 4444 541.1";

// replace "0.3 " at the beginning of the String
if (s.substring(0,4).equals("0.3 "))
    s = "32.2" + s.substring(3);

// replace " 0.3" at the end of the String
if (s.substring(s.length() - 4).equals(" 0.3"))
    s = s.substring(0, s.length() - 4) + " 32.2";

// replace all the rest of the "0.3" in the String
s = s.replaceAll(" 0.3 ", " 32.2 ");
```

---

#### Input/Output:

Input:

> "1111 1.0 2222 53.5 3333 0.3 4444 541.1"

Output:

> "1111 1.0 2222 53.5 3333 32.2 4444 541.1"

Input:

> "0.3 1111 1.0 2222 53.5 3333 0.3 4444 541.1 0.3"

Output:

> "32.2 1111 1.0 2222 53.5 3333 32.2 4444 541.1 32.2"

Input:

> "0.35 1111 1.0 2222 53.5 3333 0.3 4444 540.3"

Output:

> "0.35 1111 1.0 2222 53.5 3333 32.2 4444 540.3"

Answer (score 0):

Try using this regular expression, `\b0\.3\b`.
`\b` is a word boundary, which allows you to treat 0.3 as word.
0 is 0
`\.` represents a dot literal. You have to escape the dot because a dot in regular expressions will match any character.
3 is a literal 3.

Remember in java you have to escape the backslash, so your final regular expression is this.

`String regexp = "\\b0\\.3\\b";`

Example Junit Test

```
package demo;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Test;

public class Matchy {
    String regexp = "\\b0\\.3\\b";
    @Test
    public void test() {
        String str = "0.3 0.2 123.4 0.3 0.3 013";   
        String result = str.replaceAll(this.regexp, "32.2");
        String expect = "32.2 0.2 123.4 32.2 32.2 013";
        assertEquals(str, expect, result);
    }
    @Test
    public void test2() {
        String str = "1111 1.0 2222 53.5 3333 0.3 4444 541.1";  
        String result = str.replaceAll(this.regexp, "32.2");
        String expect = "1111 1.0 2222 53.5 3333 32.2 4444 541.1";
        assertEquals(str, expect, result);
    }

}
```

Comment: You do not "need" to use a regular expression for this.  Additionally `\\b` is a word boundary, which does not conform to a specific number of spaces surrounding the string at hand.

Comment: yea in fact whatever regular expression you come up with is going to be near impossible to decode for the next poor sap who has to read this code :)

Comment: This replaces all instances (of 0.3). I wish to remove only one specific instance (of 0.3), which can be determined by the number of spaces before the instance.

Answer (score 0):

I think this code should do what you want.

```
String str = "1111 1.0 2222 53.5 3333 0.3 4444 541.1 5555 0.3";
int numSpaces = 5;
String replacement = "32.2";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("((?:\\S+\\s+){" + numSpaces + "})(\\S+)(.*)").matcher(str);
m.find();
System.out.println("replaced " + m.group(2) + " with " + replacement + " at index " + m.start(2));
System.out.println(m.group(1) + replacement + m.group(3));
```